# How to Recover Files from Windows 10 Write-Protected Disk

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery

Three SSD setup with separate Win 10 Pro installations on two disks (0 and 2) with unique product keys.

While booted into Windows on Disk 2, I ran the current NVidia GeForce driver installer to update drivers. The installer locked the computer (spinner stopped mid-spin, mouse and keyboard unresponsive), after a few hours of waiting to be safe I hard-rebooted.

Now the drive that was running Windows during the above will not boot (stopcode registry). When I boot into Windows on the other drive (0), the volume on drive 2 mounts as normal. However, the drive itself is marked "write-protected". I can browse most non-user directories without issue, but the user directories have restricted permissions (only the user may read). To access the user directories, it seems I would need to change their permissions. But, of course cannot due to the readonly setting on the whole drive.

I've tried diskpart's `attr disk clear readonly`, which reports success. However, the disk remains write protected (Current Read-only State : Yes).

As best as I can tell, the only way to remove write protection in this case is to reformat and partition the drive. But, surely there's a way to get the data (that's sitting *right there*! :) ) off it first?

[Edit] To be clear, I'm sure I could use a third-party commercial product to do some data recovery. I'm looking for a "pure" Windows way to accomplish this--it doesn't seem like a situation that should require enhanced data recovery methods to just unravel Windows' seeming simple yet deadlocked properties and permissions.

Comment: Are these removable drives? Could they be mounted externally? Do you know anyone with a Mac? [You can just set 'ignore ownership' for anything except the boot volume on Mac, which makes this kind of task easy.]

Comment: A too-damaged disk might set itself to read-only on the firmware level. I suggest to check the SMART attributes of the disk with a product such as [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy).

Comment: These are all NVMe drives, so theoretically mountable in enclosures. All reporting OK from short and extended SMART self-tests. chkdsk reports only problems are corrupted NVidia files. In fact the only "problem" I can find is the write protection.

Comment: I was finally able to get a SMART code raised from it by trying the NVMe Secure Erase command. Until that point, even self tests all came back 100%. This was a Samsung 980 Pro 2 for the morbidly curious.

Comment: @YuriGadow Can you put up a screenshot of SMART then, preferably with Raw values visible?

Comment: I'll need to reboot into PartedMagic to do so (and figure out how to get a screenshot from Parted to anywhere else) and that machine will be tied up for a day or night more at least copying, restoring, etc. I do recall the raw code was 0x9 if that's of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows 10 recovery environment's CMD ignores NTFS permissions and includes xcopy and robocopy, either of which can be used to copy data from the problem drive to another location.

To launch that I held shift while clicking restart from the Windows login splash, Troubleshoot, Advanced Options, then Command Prompt.

From CMD, I used robocopy with the options /MIR /XJ /R:0 /W:0 to "mirror" the problem drive to another, skip the junction points that it will encounter trying to copy an entire system drive and which would lead to infinite loops, and then the last two effectively have it skip errors (those corrupt NVidia driver files). I used a locally attached drive as the destination, however I believe robocopy is able to target a public (guest mode) share without needing the share mounted to a letter first (which WinRE CMD would not support).

I could not use xcopy because I have files whose full path exceeds xcopy's 254 character limit.

Comment: so you have resolved issue?

Comment: Not to my liking, but this approach does fit my original question, i.e., how to recover files gated behind unusable NTFS permissions on a write-protected drive where they're also unalterable. I would have preferred a way within Windows to address those files so I could use software better than robocopy in a WinRE environment. But, life, lemons, all that.